# Issue with joins, SQL statement

Tags: sql

I am trying to write an SQL statement but I am having trouble. I have the following tables

**Notes**

```
person_user VARCHAR
message VARCHAR
time DATETIME
id INT (primary Key)
```

**Person**

```
name (primary key)
address VARCHAR
telephone INT
```

**Associated_With**

```
person_associating VARCHAR
person_associating_with VARCHAR
```

I need for the notes to appear, only the notes that have written by the `person_associating_with` in the `Associated_With` table.

This is my attempt as of now:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Notes 
INNER JOIN Notes.person_user ON Notes.id AS associatedMessages
INNER JOIN Associated_With On associatedMessages
WHERE 
     Person.name = person_associating
ORDER BY 
     time DESC;
```

At the moment I am getting all possible results back, regardless of the query

Comment: And so what is going wrong? Query error? Incorrect result? EDIT: A syntax error by the looks of it.

Comment: What is the schema of your `associatedMessages` table?

Comment: `INNER JOIN associatedMessages`. You can only `JOIN` to a table.

Comment: SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name; (this is the basic structure you should be following)

Comment: therefore if you are joining Notes to Person you probably want a person.id as a foreign key in your notes table. That way you have something to join the two tables together on, unless person_user is a foreign key that is really name_person. Then you can do something like SELECT * from Notes JOIN Person ON notes.person_user = person.name...

Comment: What flavor of SQL is this for? MySQL? Postgres? IBM DB2? Oracle? SQL Server? Please update your tags accordingly!

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are looking for the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM Notes AS ABB2 
   JOIN Associated_With AS ABB1 ON 
       ABB1.person_associating_with = ABB2.person_user
ORDER BY time DESC
```

In your original query, you are trying to join tables with both ON conditions and WHERE conditions.  While it's possible to do so, it's best to use one or the other for consistency.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you might not be looking for joins but an IN statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM Notes
WHERE person_user IN
    (SELECT person_associating_with
     FROM Associated_With);
```